# Capturing the output of a PowerShell process started from a WPF app

Tags: c#

I am trying to do some operations in the WPF application based on the PowerShell output that is captured and stored in a `.log` file.

I have a WPF application that takes some configurations and starts a PowerShell process. The output of the Powershell scripts is written as they are being executed in a `.log` file and keeps on updating until the scripts are fully executed. The Code for starting the PowerShell process looks like this:

```
private void OpenPowershell(string path, string script, string logFile, string type)
{
    try
    {
        BtnExecute.IsEnabled = false;
        bool is64 = IntPtr.Size == 8;
        var ENV = "Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\* "
               + (is64 ? ",HKLM:\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\*" : "")
               + " | Select-Object DisplayName";
        ProcessStartInfo startInstall = new ProcessStartInfo(path, ENV);
        startInstall.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInstall.Arguments = script;
        startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardOutput", "true");
        startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("RedirectStandardError", "true");
        startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("UseShellExecute", "false");
        startInstall.EnvironmentVariables.Add("CreateNoWindow", "true");
        Process Install = Process.Start(startInstall);
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Install.Close();
        txtInstallationStarted.Text = $"Installation Started... More details can be found at {logFile}";
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}
private void ProcessSectionScript1(List<string> sectionData)
{
    if (sectionData.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (sectionData.ToString().Contains("error"))
    {
        Script1Error = true;
    }
    if (Script1Error)
    {
        Script1StatusStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Script1Fail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Script1Check.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Script1TextBlock.Text = "Script1 Installation Failed";
    }
    else
    {
        Script1StatusStack.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Script1Check.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Script1Fail.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        Script1TextBlock.Text = "Script1 Installed Successfully";
    }
}
```

This PS script also executes a bunch of other scripts and I need to do some UI changes based on the output. The execution of the PS scripts can be differentiated too as I have lines such as:

```
Script 1 started
//lines
Script 1 complete
Script 2 started
//lines
Script 2 complete
.
.
```

From `Script 1` to `Script 2`, I need to check if a line containing "Error" is displayed. If it is, I need to enable a component and if not, I need to enable another indicating that everything was correct. This needs to be then checked for `Script 2` to `Script 3`.

For example, if I see something like this:

```
Script 1
Error in executing xyz command
Script 2
```

I need to do something like this:

```
Script1Success.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
Script1Fail.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

I cannot seem to make it work. With this, I'm having the following problems:

The `if (sectionData.ToString().Contains("error")` does not get `true` even if there is an error in the line.

Also, I think the execution is wrong. Please note that from the time you press the button to start the Powershell scripts to the `.log` file being created. There is a small delay of maybe 2-3 seconds because the Powershell window needs to open and start which is why I have added `Thread.Sleep(3000);`.

I was thinking that perhaps I need to split it up in sections from `Script 1` to `Script 2` so that I can check them accordingly. However, I cannot seem to make it work and right now, it just shows the `Completed` icon visibility regardless of the status.

If further clarification is required about what I am trying to do, I'll update the question. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: i really worry about the stability. are you creating some dashboard for script execution status?

Comment: Yes I need to display kind of like a summary of the status of the scripts. If an error is spotted in the execution of any of the scripts, I'll just make visible a `Red Cross Icon` and if not, a `Green Check` to indicate the status.

Comment: since the log is flushing quickly, i think you'd better consider other IPC methods, such as named pipes.

Comment: @LeiYang I was thinking of maybe doing `startInstall.RedirectStandardOutput` to true and using that to read the stream. But I don't really know how to properly execute it and read it.

Comment: i think read output is still unstable.

Comment: What can I do instead then?

Comment: your have serveral questions, such as architecture design/technical choices, how to capture output/monitor log change, how to update wpf ui. please focus on single question(better update your question).